# Android WebView not using ETag for proper caching

Tags: android, webview, browser-cache, etag

I use a WebView in Android/Kotlin with

```
settings.cacheMode = LOAD_DEFAULT
```

The server does not return any **Cache-Control:** header! But it returns valid **ETag** headers for all requests.

What I want is, that the WebView is sending all requests with the **If-None-Match:** header set to only download files if it is really needed. If the tag matches, it should use the 304 header returned by the server.

But I find the WebView is caching all the time. At least for 10 minutes or more. Looks very random. And it does not seem to send the **If-None-Match:** header at all because the server never replies with 304 header.

If I disable the cache for the WebView (cacheMode = LOAD_NO_CACHE), it is also not using the ETag. Instead, it always loads everything (as expected).

How can I make the WebView use the Etag to handle caching? Short requests and using ETag would be perfect.

It is for a web app and it should only fully reload bigger ressources if they really have changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is, that Android WebView is not capable of using **ETag** headers for caching properly. It does some internal caching only.

It is possible to implement the use of **ETag** and **If-Modified-Since** headers by using callbacks.

I found a site that shows how this is done:
https://medium.com/android-news/reducing-your-networking-footprint-with-okhttp-etags-and-if-modified-since-b598b8dd81a1

In short words, you intercept the traffic and build your own caching system around your own **ETag** and **If-Modified-Since** headers.